# When dealing with Tabu Search Optimization, what is the common practice when all of the neighbouring solutions are tabu?

Tags: algorithm, search, optimization, tabu-search

Does laxing the criterion for a 'neighbour' suffice or is there another standard action to take?

Answer (score 0):

If all the neighbouring solutions are Tabu it sounds like either the size of your Tabu list is too long or your freeing strategy is too strict. A good Tabu list length is root(n).
You could however select the neighbouring solution that is the oldest Tabu or select none of them and continue the search from a different variable.